# monitor cannot be detected, missing a driver?

Tags: 11.10, monitor

I have a Dell XPS i5.
I installed Ubuntu 11.10, but it cannot detect my Samsung monitor. I don't know if i'm missing a driver, i'm currently using a NVIDIA GPU.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your monitor is using a digital or analog single. Is there a menu option in your monitor settings that will change the input to digital of analog? Also, this can be due to a incorrect adapter depending if the video card outputs in digital or analog. Make sure you are using the correct connector (d-sub, dvi, or vga).